# Entire layout is fine until a word is not inserted in box1/box2/box3. If i add a single word in any div my design got disturbed

Tags: html, css

```css
<style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .navbar {
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
            }

            .navbar ul li {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-top: 20px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }

            .box1 {
                background-color: red;
                width: 33.3333333%;
                height: 600px;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .box2 {
                background-color: blue;
                width: 33.3333333%;
                height: 600px;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .box3 {
                background-color: greenyellow;
                width: 33.3333333%;
        height: 600px;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .bottombar {
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                height: 50px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
```

```html
<doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
  </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Contact us</li>
        </div><div class="box1">
        </div><div class="box2">
        </div><div class="box3"> 
        </div><div class="bottombar"> &copy copyright reserved 2020-2021</div>>

    </body>

    </html>
```

> Here i made three boxes box1,box2 and box 3 of different colours of
> three different colors and managed to arrange them side by side along
> width using CSS property (display: inline-block).But when I insert a
> single letter in any of these boxes ,that box goes down.

Comment: Why is it doing this? the white space from elements in HTML is basically set, i post you an answer under :) hope it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem, the thing im using is a margin-right of -0.25em on all elements inside, there is probably other solutions but this is mine

```css
<style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .navbar {
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
            }

            .navbar ul li {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-top: 20px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }

            .container div{
                margin-right: -0.25em;
            }

            .box1 {
                background-color: red;
                width: 33.3333333%;
                height: 600px;
                display: inline-block;     
            }

            .box2 {
                background-color: blue;
                width: 33.3333333%;
                height: 600px;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .box3 {
                background-color: greenyellow;
                width: 33.3333333%;
                height: 600px;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .bottombar {
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                height: 50px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
```

```html
<doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
  </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Contact us</li>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box1">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="box2">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="box3"> 
                test
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottombar"> &copy copyright reserved 2020-2021</div>>

    </body>

    </html>
```